# How to get around payload in Elasticsearch 5.0

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm in the process to upgrade my old Elasticsearch cluster to Elasticsearch 5.0.

I noticed that they removed `payload` from Elasticsearch 5.0 and that's been preventing me from successfully upgrading Elasticsearch.

I realized that `payload` appears many times in my code. The following are my code snippets that include `payload`.

```
elasticClient.index({
  index: "users",
  type: "user",
  id: username,
  body: {
    name_suggest: {
      input: displayname
      payload: { "user_id": username }
    }
  }
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I'm using React.js(JSX) and Express.js to show the search results in the following snippet.

```
return (
  <ul id="searchValue" key="wow">
    {result.options[0] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[0].payload.user_id}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[0].payload.user_id }>{ result.options[0].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[1] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[1].payload.user_id}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[1].payload.user_id }>{ result.options[1].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[2] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[2].payload.user_id}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[2].payload.user_id}>{ result.options[2].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[3] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[3].payload.user_id}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[3].payload.user_id}>{ result.options[3].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[4] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[4].payload.user_id}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[4].payload.user_id}>{ result.options[4].text}</li></a> : null}
  </ul>
)
```

As you can see, I use `payload` many times.

In Elasticsearch 5.0, how do I need to update the code to make it work without `payload`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete every line with `payload` and use `_source` instead as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_suggester.html#_completion_suggester_is_document_oriented).

For example:

```
return (
  <ul id="searchValue" key="wow">
    {result.options[0] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[0]._source.name_suggest.input}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[0]._source.name_suggest.input}>{ result.options[0].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[1] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[1]._source.name_suggest.input}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[1]._source.name_suggest.input}>{ result.options[1].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[2] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[2]._source.name_suggest.input}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[2]._source.name_suggest.input}>{ result.options[2].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[3] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[3]._source.name_suggest.input}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[3]._source.name_suggest.input}>{ result.options[3].text}</li></a> : null}
    {result.options[4] ? <a href={"users/" + result.options[4]._source.name_suggest.input}><li style={{display: this.state.searchResults}} key={ result.options[4]._source.name_suggest.input}>{ result.options[4].text}</li></a> : null}
  </ul>
)
```

Change `payload.user_id` to `_source.name_suggest.input`.

I also deleted the line `payload: { "user_id": username }` since it was not required in Elasticsearch 5.0.